# what is [k] thread_return in perf outpout

Tags: linux, perf

I am trying to detect performance bottle necks in my multi-threaded application and the perf results show me that 20% of cpu is being hogged by this top entry

```
  21.37%  [kernel]                  [k] thread_return
```

I am trying to understand what is this and what causes this . I couldn't find relevant data on google so kindly suggest .

Comment: it is kernel code, when you clean up your threads. You either do it very often and many times, or you do very few work in the thread itself.

Comment: by clean up do  you mean destructor ? I have 4 threads which start when program starts and are terminated at the end only . Yes these 4 threads are doing small work . Can you please share source as well so tha ti can look more

Comment: Yes, something like that, I think.